# Yank all function names in a file

Tags: regular-expression

How would I yank all the function names in a file?

---

For example in C, you might want to take all your function definitions in `foo.c`, and grab them for declarations in your header file `foo.h`.

```
void hello(int a) {
  ...
}
void hello2(char b) {
  ...
}
```

becomes

```
void hello(int a);
void hello2(char b);
```

---

In Python, you might want to export your functions declared in a module `foo/foo.py` by importing all of them in `foo/__init__.py`

```
def hello(a):
    ...
def hello2(b):
    ...
```

becomes

```
from foo import hello, hello2
```

Comment: For C there's [cproto](http://invisible-island.net/cproto/cproto.html).  For other filetypes you should probably just run `ctags` and munge the resulting `tags` file.  Some combinations of flags might make your life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first, you need to be more clear about what exactly you expect a function to look like. For example, you could say a C function looks like

> A word at the beginning of a line, followed by whitespace, followed by one more word, followed by any number of spaces, followed by a parenthesis.

However, this could definitely have some false positives. For example, this is *clearly* not a function:

```
/*
this is_not_a_function(but it looks like one);
*/
```

You might change this so that the line must end with an opening bracket. But that will not match

```
int foo() { //Foo is a function!
...
}
```

So you might say there must be an opening bracket *somewhere*. But that will have a false positive, e.g.

```
int foo; //Haha, broke your regex() {
```

and it will not match this valid function:

```
int foo()
{
...
}
```

So it will be very hard to make a foolproof regex that *only* matches functions, and matches *every* function.

Regardless, here's a start. You will probably have to modify this to make it match your data better, but I can at least put you on the right track.

```
:let @a=""
:g/\v^(<\w+>\s*){2}\(/normal "AY
```

Explanation:

First, clear out register "a" with `:let @a=""`. Then, we can use the `:g` command to yank every line that matches our regex, and append it to register `"a`. (Capital A means append to the register, rather than overwrite). This is the regex:

```
\v^(<\w+>\s*){2}\(
```

The `\v` means "magic". This just makes the regex shorter. Without it, we would have to do:

```
^\(\<\w\+\>\s*\)\{2}(
```

Then we have `(<\w+>\s*)` which means a word, then any amount of whitespace. Then `{2}`, which means two of the previous atom. Then `\(` which is a literal left parenthesis. Since we have `^` at the beginning, this will only match if it's at the beginning of the line.

The python regex is much simpler:

```
/def[^#]*:
```

This is "def", followed by any number of non "#" characters, followed by a colon.

Comment: In Python(just like in C)someone could put a function in a multiline string: `"""`.  I guess such that context-sensitivity is a limitation of a simple regular expression and would require tokenizing to be robust

Comment: `#`s never come after def in python. I've seen them immediately before though. I think `/^def.*:` is safer. The regex to yank I used was `:g/\v^def <\w+>.*:.*/normal "AY`. I do not know how to only yank a group with `:g` so the second round after pasting the output into a buffer is `%s/\v^def (<\w+>).*/\1`

Comment: @BryceGuinta "`#`s never come after def in python" - Not true! [Python functions can get really stupid](https://git.io/vKIRP). `#` can be present in a default keyword string. It's also possible for a comment to be on the same line as the function or within it's arguments if it's multiline. If you really want the full function signature, a safer pattern would be `^\s*def\_[^:]\{-}:`, though it's still possible for `:` to be in a string. But, your question says you only need the function name, so `^\s*def\s\+\k\+` would be good enough.